# Iterating over a function to combine many raster stacks into one

Tags: r, raster, netcdf4

Been stuck on this for a while now.  Looked everywhere for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything on Stack.  Any help you all can give that would be very appreciated.

My main issue is that I need to import many, many netcdf4 files, create raster bricks of each, then combine many bricks to make a "master brick" per variable.  To give you a clearer example, I have 40 years (netcdf = 40) of many climate variables (n = 15) that are at a daily resolution.  The goal is to aggregate to monthly, but first I have to get this function that reads all years of netcdf's for one variable in and into one large stack.

What I have now reads as follows:

```
# Libraries --------------------------------------------------------------
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

# Directories -------------------------------------------------------------

tmp_dl <- list.files("/Users/NateM", pattern = "nc",
                 full.names = TRUE)
# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------
rstlist = stack()

netcdf_import <- function(file) {
   nc <- nc_open(file)
   nc_att <- attributes(nc$var)$names
   ncvar <- ncvar_get(nc, nc_att)
   rm(nc)
   proj <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
   rbrck <- brick(ncvar, crs= proj)
   rm(ncvar)
   extent(rbrck) <- c(-124.772163391113, -67.06383005778, 25.0626894632975, 
                       49.3960227966309) 
   }      

t <- for(i in 1:length(tmp_dl)) {
         x <- netcdf_import(tmp_dl[i])
         rstlist <- stack(rstlist, x)
      }

allyears <- stack(t)
```

Two years of the data can be found here:

https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pdsi_2016.nc
https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pdsi_2015.nc

Any help would be most welcomed. Thank you all in advance, and if this is a duplicate post I apologize; I looked far and wide to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to `return` the loaded brick `rbrck` from your function, otherwise you'll get the extent.

As for loading and stacking, I'd suggest using `lapply` to apply the function to each datafile. This will give you a neat list with a year per item. There you could do some more processing and finally just call `stack` on the list to produce your "master brick".

Mind that I only did this with two files, so I'm not sure about the size of the whole thing when you do it with 40.

Here's your modified code:

```
# Libraries --------------------------------------------------------------
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

# Directories -------------------------------------------------------------

tmp_dl <- list.files("/Users/NateM", pattern = "nc",
                     full.names = TRUE)
# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------

netcdf_import <- function(file) {
  nc <- nc_open(file)
  nc_att <- attributes(nc$var)$names
  ncvar <- ncvar_get(nc, nc_att)
  rm(nc)
  proj <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
  rbrck <- brick(ncvar, crs= proj)
  rm(ncvar)
  extent(rbrck) <- c(-124.772163391113, -67.06383005778, 25.0626894632975, 
                     49.3960227966309) 
  return(rbrck)
}      

# apply function
allyrs <- lapply(tmp_dl,netcdf_import)

# stack to master brick
allyrs <- do.call(stack,allyrs)
```

HTH

Comment: Hey Val - thanks a lot for that edit, worked like a charm!  Also, appreciate the suggestion with lapply - I have to get better at using that function.  Many thanks!