# for loop to stack raster images?

Tags: r, stack, geospatial, raster

I am attempting to open 58 files from a directory named

```
ncfiles <- list.files("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height", full.names = T, pattern = "*.nc")
```

By using a `for` loop with `TryCatch` to rapidly open the files within the folder, my goal is to create a raster stack image composed of all 58 raster files. My loop runs through to completion but I am having trouble producing an image. I have followed examples similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227161/iterating-over-a-function-to-combine-many-raster-stacks-into-one) but cannot figure out my issue. Can someone please let me know what I'm missing? I am not sure how to attach an appropriate, reproducible example for my case.

```
bigstack <- stack()
```

LOOP:

```
for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
  GetMyImage <- tryCatch(        
    {
      fname <-(ncfiles[i])
      f <- nc_open(fname)
      print(fname)
    },
error=function(e) {
  message('Caught Error')
  print(e)
},
warning=function(w) {
  message('Caught Warning')
  print(w)
},
finally = {
  message('All done')
}
)
  if(inherits(errorCondition("ERROR :", next)))
 {
  ah <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "DETAILED_RESULTS/aerosol_optical_thickness")
  lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
  lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
  nc_close(f)
   s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
   crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
   ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))
   pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)
   pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)
   exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))
   levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))
   bigstack <- stack(bigstack, pmraster)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not answer your question directly, but have you tried to just run `stack(ncfiles)`? I have always done it this way and always worked. Rasters should have same extent and resolution, though.

/Emilio

Comment: When I try that, I get the error: "Error in xx[-length(xx)] - xx[-1] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
  DETAILED_RESULTS/covariance_matrix has more than 4 dimensions, I do not know what to do with these data"