# lapply creates endless loop when attempting to stack rasters

Tags: r, for-loop, geospatial, lapply, raster

I am attempting to produce a single raster image composed of other stacked raster images from my directory:

```
ncfiles <- list.files("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height", full.names = T, pattern = "*.nc")
```

When I follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227161/iterating-over-a-function-to-combine-many-raster-stacks-into-one), and run this loop:

```
bigstack <- stack()

test <- function(file) { for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
  GetMyImage <- tryCatch(        
    {
      fname <-(ncfiles[i])
      f <- nc_open(fname)
      print(fname)
    },
    error=function(e) {
      message('Caught Error')
      print(e)
    },
    warning=function(w) {
      message('Caught Warning')
      print(w)
    },
    finally = {
      message('All done')
    }
  )
  if(inherits(errorCondition("ERROR :", next)))
  {
    varx <- attributes(f$var) $names
    vary <- ncvar_get(f, varx)
    rm(f)
    proj <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
    rbrick <- brick(vary, crs=proj)
    rm(vary)
    extent(rbrick) <- c(-180, -140, 10, 30)
    return(rbrick)
  }}}
```

Then attempt to stack:

```
allyrs <- lapply(ncfiles, test)
```

My loop runs on repeat, nonstop. What is causing my loop to run endlessly? And how may I produce the desired stacked raster image? Thanks for any input!

Comment: One contributor to the problem could be that you're running a for loop inside your `test` function. `lapply` already applies `test` to all the files in `ncfiles`, so there's no need to loop within `test` itself. Try removing the `for` statement, and replacing `ncfiles[i]` with `file` (the argument to the `test` function)

Comment: What do you intend to be doing with `inherits(errorCondition(...))`? First, `inherits` takes *two* arguments, `x=` (the object) and `what=` (1 or more strings indicating classes against which the object-class is compared); you're missing `what`. Second, `errorCondition` is designed to always put something out of class `"error"`, that is its function, so using that directly with `inherits` makes no sense to me, even if you did provide a second argument to `inherits`. Third, `next` is a reserved word meant to be used in some loop (e.g., `for`, `while`), not as an argument to a function.

Comment: You could just read in by `do.call(raster::stack, lapply(raster::raster, ncfiles))` if all of your rasters are the same extent and ncfiles is the list of your raster files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem here was making the loop too complicated and containing counter intuitive components like what was previously suggested in the comments. I reformatted the loop to:

```
ncfiles <- list.files("~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height", full.names = T, pattern = "*.nc")

bigstack <- stack()

for (i in 1: length(ncfiles)){
      fname <-(ncfiles[i])
      f <- nc_open(fname)
  ah <- ncvar_get(f, varid = "DETAILED_RESULTS/aerosol_optical_thickness")
  lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
  lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
  nc_close(f)
   s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
   crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
   ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))
   pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)
   pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)
   exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))
   levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))
   bigstack <- stack(bigstack, pmraster)
   print("test")
}

stacking <- calc(bigstack, fun=mean, na.rm=T)
levelplot(crop(stacking, exHI))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep things more modular. First a function that does you want for one file

```
open_one_file <- function(fname) {
    f <- nc_open(fname)
    varx <- attributes(f$var) $names
    vary <- ncvar_get(f, varx)
    proj <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
    rbrick <- brick(vary, crs=proj)
    extent(rbrick) <- c(-180, -140, 10, 30)
    return(rbrick)
}
```

Now get the filenames

```
ncfiles <- list.files(full.names = T, pattern = "\\.nc$")
```

Test the function with a few files. For example

```
test <- open_one_file(ncfiles[3])
```

If this works for some files, use a loop or `lapply` to read them all. Apparently some fail, so I added a `try` clause.

```
x <- lapply(ncfiles, function(i) try(open_one_file(i)))
```

If you have failing files it may easier to use a loop

```
x <- list()
for (i in 1:length(ncfiles)) {
    print(i); print(ncfiles[i]); flush.console()
    x[[i]] <- open_one_file(ncfiles[i]) 
 }
```

And you can combine the RasterBricks in list `x` like this

```
y <- stack(x)
```

As @at80 points out, with standard ncdf files you would rather do

```
x <- lapply(ncfiles, brick)
```

Or

```
x <- lapply(ncfiles, function(f) brick(f, var="variable names"))
```

followed again by

```
y <- stack(x)
```